# How to check input value given by user doesn't contain any characters?

Tags: c++, char, double

I want to store a value in double (ex. 1234567890) but when user enter any letter ( ex. 12345a6789) my program goes hang. How can I check whether input value is legal or not?

```
double num;
cout<< "Enter the number:";
cin>>num;

//How to check?
if( num is illegal )
{
cout << "Error";
return;
}
else
{
//code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number can't tell anything if the input was correct. Instead you should check the input operation itself for failing:

```
double num;
cout<< "Enter the number:";
if(!(cin>>num)) {
    // invalid input ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get your input value as `string` and then use `std::stod` to convert to `double`.`std::stod` throws `invalid_argument` `exception` if no conversion could be performed.